Dimension, characteristic, geometry (soft question)
Even though it is often called a line, the dimension of the scheme $A^1_{\mathbb{Z}} =\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is two.
According to my understanding, there is another much more sophisticated algebraicized notion of dimension, where for a curve over an algebraically closed field (another supposedly dimension 1 thing) one also gets 2 instead of 1.
Namely, etale theory shifts the cohomology groups of the curve to be in degrees 0, 1, and 2, making it look more like a topological surface with the singular theory (which indeed it is in the analytic, characteristic 0 case).
Question. Is this a coincidence? Does it have any connection to the ''field with one element'' idea?
If $\mathbb{F}_1$ is something we want in order to geometrize the integers, would it be complete nonsense to say that we want the etale topology for curves over it to be the usual Zariski topology?

There is not even a coincidence to be discussed here. In étale cohomology the dimensions of (say) projective varieties over an algebraically closed field are doubled, not shifted by 1, compared to Krull dimension. This is like how complex algebraic curves (complex dimension 1) are also Riemann surfaces (real dimension 2). But it is the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ that is 2, which is because $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ itself already has Krull dimension 1.

Will accept if you post as answer

There is not even a coincidence to be discussed here.
In étale cohomology (and related theories), the dimension of (say) a projective variety over an algebraically closed field is doubled, not shifted by 1, compared to its Krull dimension.
This is like how complex algebraic curves / Riemann surfaces have complex dimension 1 and real dimension 2.
But it is the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ that is 2, which is because $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ itself already has Krull dimension 1.
In case it is still not clear what I am saying, perhaps it is worth noting that étale cohomology tells us the dimension of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is $2 n$, whereas the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{Z}$ is $n + 1$.
This property of étale cohomology is essentially by design: we seek a cohomology theory for algebraic varieties that has formal properties similar to singular cohomology for complex manifolds.
You might wonder what étale cohomology tells us about $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.
Unfortunately, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ itself behaves like a contractible space, but the story is much more interesting if you imagine $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ can be embedded in some kind of complete algebraic curve with an additional point corresponding to the archimedean valuation of $\mathbb{Q}$.
From what I hear, it ends up acting like a 3-sphere...
